# Multi-dimensional array from SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an multi-dimensional array that I am trying to build from an SQL query. I am having trouble adding the `id` in the inner array.

Code:

```
$checkboxes = "SELECT id, name FROM review_sites WHERE active=1 ORDER BY name ASC"; 
$result = mysql_query($checkboxes) or die(mysql_error());
$names = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $names[]['name'] = $row['name'];

}
```

Currently the Array looks like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => 411.ca
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => AutoMD
    )
```

I Need the array to look like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => 411.ca
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 9
        [name] => AutoMD
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only selecting `id` and `name` in the query so, in the loop:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $names[] = $row;
}
```

Or simply:

```
while ($names[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {}
```

Notice, `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to only return an associative array.  `mysql_fetch_array()` returns an associative and numerically indexed array.

Also:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
>   See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include:
>   mysqli_fetch_array() PDOStatement::fetch()

If you were to use the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension then you may be able to use:

```
$names = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$checkboxes = "SELECT id, name FROM review_sites WHERE active=1 ORDER BY name ASC"; 
$result = mysql_query($checkboxes) or die(mysql_error());
$names = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
    $names['id'] = $row['name'];

}   

var_dump($names);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.